# Elastic Beanstalk `War` deploy - 404 Not Found

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, war, tomcat8

I am trying to deploy a Java Spring MVC `war` file on Elastic Beanstalk and I am having trouble understanding how to resolve a `404 Not found` error.

I have zipped and named correctly the `war` file and the status of the EB instance is `OK`. However, when I click on the EB url `XXXX.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com` I am getting the above mentioned Tomcat error.

I looked in the log files and the only ERROR that is displayed in there is 
[image]

> server is within MinSpareThreads of MaxClients, consider raising the MaxClients setting

I am not fully confident I know how to increase the MaxClients number but I am also not convinced that this is where the error comes from, so I was wondering if you could advice how this could be resolved.

Many thanks in advace!

Comment: have you tried to add port number to url (like `XXXX.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com:8080`)? is your app still running after error that you mentioned above?

Comment: @VasiliySarzhynskyi yes I have but the app doesn't load when a port number is added.. I may add a bounty to this question at a later stage as I really don't have a clue what the problem might be

Comment: This is an AWS bug - see stackoverflow.com/a/51978173/786110. You need to add a valid war file and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is built using Spring Boot, you need to update it to Deploy WAR file to Tomcat. Meaning explicitly you need to mention the main class to run on deployment.

Read detailed steps from here. https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/